# Two errors when sign-in google plus - JAVA ANDROID STUDIO

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio

I generated my application and I'm getting two main errors when i'm debugging it and app is forced to close.

Take a look, here is an error:
http://pastebin.com/UarfA6yH

Here is layout in XML:
http://pastebin.com/wia6ewRU

And here is ActivityMainWallet.java:
http://pastebin.com/DduZ8tLd

Please help me! Thanks!

Comment: The error because `Value v2 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject` so check your code when parsing JSON

Comment: @Sodiq i fixed it by deleting Charboost line i activity, but the problem is still with XML.

Comment: whats your log?

Comment: @Sodiq http://pastebin.com/mKSP2a4x

Comment: try to add `setSupportActionBar(drawerToolbar);` after `drawerToolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.drawer_toolbar);`